# Expression failure

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I've got such expression:

```
Linq2Rest.Reactive.InnerRestObservable`1[A]
    .Where(item => (Convert(IIF((item != null), item.ID, 0)) == Convert(61)))
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(20)
```

When I invoke [Subscribe method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402849%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on it I recieve such error:

> variable 'item' of type 'A' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Can't figure out what is the problem. Actually can't see any problems with item argument...

UPD.
Where clause built with this code:

```
public static IQbservable WhereExpression(this IQbservable query, Expression filterExpression, ParameterExpression instance = null)
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item"); // NOI18N

            var filteredQuery = (IQbservable)GenericsHelper.InvokeGenericExtensionMethod(
                typeof(Qbservable),
                "Where", // NOI18N
                new[] { query.ElementType },
                query,
                Expression.Lambda(filterExpression, instance)
            );

            return filteredQuery;
        }
public static object InvokeGenericExtensionMethod(
            Type extensionClass,
            string extensionMethodName,
            Type[] genericTypes,
            params object[] parameters
        )
        {
            var method = extensionClass.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m =>
                m.Name == extensionMethodName &&
                m.IsGenericMethod &&
                m.GetGenericArguments().Length == genericTypes.Length &&
                m.GetParameters().Length == parameters.Length
            );

            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} doesn't contain method {1}", extensionClass.Name, extensionMethodName)); // NOI18N

            var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypes);

            return genericMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
        }
```

UPD 2. This is how WhereExpression calls:

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "item"); // NOI18N
                query = query.WhereExpression(filter.CreateFilterExpression(paramExpression), paramExpression);
            }
```

filters is collection of IFilterDescriptor interface from telerik.

Comment: What is the back tick before `1`? Some kind of `.NET 6.0` feature?

Comment: @KingKing: It's the name of a generic class. it has been like this since generics have been introduced in .NET 2.0. Example: `new List<string>().GetType().ToString()` yields `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]`

Comment: @Pavel: Who builds this expression? If you build it with code, please show this code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you mean I can use back tick to name a class? in what version of .NET?

Comment: @KingKing: The type name is not language specific. What you see here is the actual type name in IL. In C# you have to use the normal generics syntax. Please also see the example in my previous comment.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks, I still don't understand, I remember I saw it somewhere in some exception/error message but how could the compiler not complain about it? That's invalid to name a class, it may be valid in `IL` but not in C# code, right?

Comment: @KingKing: Yes, it is invalid C# code. And you don't write that in C#. Please read and understand the example I have given. As you can see, the C# code uses the normal C# generics syntax. The C# compiler translates this into IL and thereby uses the IL type name.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Hey, I updated my post with code u asked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the *same* ParameterExpression instance both as the parameter and in the body of the expression.

The easiest thing would be to simply use the one from the filter expression, by using it completely.

Comment: I pass the instance of ParameterExpression and it is the only one that passed to Expression.Lambda(filterExpression, instance) as instance variable. So there is only one ParameterExpression.

Comment: @Pavel.S.: Please show how you call `WhereExpression`. Please note that the body of the filter expression contains a reference to an ParameterExpression instance. This is the one you need to use throughout.

Comment: See upd 2. for details.

Comment: and actually I can't figure out how can I get ParameterExpression from BinaryExpression...

Comment: David is right. There seems to be a problem in the way you create your Where expression. You are creating numerous instances and passing them to the expression. You should use only the one you create with your lambda expression and pass that to your expression. So create the parameter outside the foreach loop and pass that single instance.

Comment: In a BinaryExpression the ParameterExpression will be either the Left or the Right expression. You can find it by Expression.Kind property.